# Renaming table column with expression in the Field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler, rename

I want to be able to rename a few column names with an expression in the Field calculator in order to be able reproduce this action with the QGIS Graphical Modeler.

I tried to do this with the "Refactor fields" tool of the modeler which works but the information of my columns disappears. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tried to use the refactoring tool and I keep my information. Can you edit your post and attach a screenshot of your tool settings?

Comment: Indeed, the refactor fields do works for this case, there must be some syntax errors in your model. Share some screenshots.

Comment: Possibly workaround: Use the fieldcalculator to create a new field with the desired name and just copy the column you want to rename, then delete the old/wrongly named column - which should be possibly via the modeler.

Answer (score 3):

To rename column names using **QGIS Graphical Modeler**, this is how I would approach it. I am using **QGIS 3.6.3** in this example.

[image]

1. Before launching the Graphical Modeler, add a sample layer that contains the initial columns. After which open the Graphical Modeler.
2. Once the Graphical Modeler is opened, add a layer from the **Input tab**. Choose all the appropriate options that would be required.
   [image]
3. Add the Refactoring Algorithm from the **Algorithm tab**. Once the Refactoring Algorithm has been added, load fields from the sample layer you added at the beginning.
4. From the loaded fields, the **Source expression** are the old columns and the **Field name** will be the new names you want the columns to have. Rename the columns as desired.
5. Enter a name for the new layer and click OK.
6. You can save the model. Then run it, a new layer should be added the with the columns having new names.

I tested it and it worked for me.